# Skil circular saw

Tags: electrical

I replaced my trigger and looked at the wiring diagram before install to make sure it was correct when I pulled the trigger my garage breaker tripped.  Reset breaker and it did it again.  Opened saw and checked wiring to see if wires were ok and they were, looked to see if wire was possibly grounded but it was no and ground wire was good also. Pulled new trigger out and checked for continuity and it was good.  Could the new trigger be bad? The old trigger worked fine it was just that the clicking in the trigger stopped and I just wanted to replace the trigger. Any thoughts on why it is tripping?

Comment: Make sure you didn't damage the insulation when screwing the frame back together.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Sounds like your circuit breaker is doing it's job, but there's no way we could tell why from here. One question: is this a GFCI breaker, and is that what's tripping? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Did you rewire it the way you found it? Generally switches involve precisely 2 wires. *Did you do anything with a third wire?*